# in Sitecore 10.3.0 , Sitecore.Reporting.Client.ReportingClient is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: xconnect

In my current undertaking with Sitecore version 10.3.0, I am in the process of extracting data from the reporting API. However, an error has arisen, as illustrated by the screenshot below.

[image]

After reviewing the definition of ReportingClient, it becomes evident that the issue may be attributed to the class having an Internal Access Modifier. I need help to mitigate this issue. thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well your only immediate option would be to use reflection to invoke it.

```
ConstructorInfo ctor = GetType("Sitecore.Reporting.Client.ReportingClient").GetConstructors
    (BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)[0];

var reportingClient = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { "test" });
```

Something along those lines.

That said, this class was likely marked `internal` for good reason. You should probably check your implementation methodology and look around for a different approach.